# How to link the relational datatables and divide the sum of 3 columns from one table by 1 column in another table using SQL SELECT query

Tags: sql, select

I'm creating a database for Formula 1 drivers/teams. The idea is to display the cost comparisons of team budgets vs team points and driver salaries, to see the effective cost per point for the top 10 teams.

E.g from 2015 info

> Team Mercedes
>
> Income received = euro 467.4m (sponsors 122m, partners 212.40m, tv 133m).
>
> Points Scored = 703 (total from both drivers: Hamilton 381, Rosberg 322).
>
> Effective Cost Per Point = 2,506,417.11

I have 3 datatables: One each for the team, the drivers, and a table to join tables 1&2 together, to then create the correct `SELECT` queries:

```
Table 'team'
teamid
teamname
sponsors
partners
tv
total

Table 'driver'
driverid
drivername
salary
points

Table 'driverteam'
teamid
driverid
totalbudget
totalpoints
```

I first need to get the sum of the sponsors,partners and tv so I have created the following `SELECT` statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT teamname, sum(sponsors+partners+tv) as total FROM team ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10";
```

I know how to get the salary and points from a driver:

```
$sql = "SELECT drivername, salary FROM driver ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 10";

$sql = "SELECT drivername, points FROM driver ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Seems ok, but now comes my problem, how to get the `SUM` from table 1 and divide it by the points that the drivers have got in table 2.

My limited brain says I need a `INNER JOIN` using table 3 to get table 1 & 2 together, before performing the necessary divisions etc.

As there are 2 drivers per team, I need to divide the team total budget by each drivers' points, as well as the team total by both drivers points.

What `SELECT` queries do I need to achieve this?

Comment: can a driver ever belong to more than one team at a time?

Comment: Hi @VikingBlooded, thanks for your question. The answer is no, a driver only belongs to one team at a time and there are always 2 drivers per team. :)

Comment: Thanks @CubeJockey for the de-fluffing :)